# IntelliJ 2018.3 EAP Google Cloud Tools Login Errors

Tags: google-cloud-intellij

Whilst I wasn't exactly expecting everything to be operational on a beta release product, I'm just reporting the following errors for cloud-tools on the new EAP release of IntelliJ. Not 100% sure if this is an error due to my own configuration or a current bug, though it was immediately after upgrading to the new EAP release.

Mainly wanting to get into Git submodules as they are now supported in this EAP.

My bad, edit to include errors:

Not Loaded. The plugin com.google.gct.login is disabled.

Comment: Hi. We are working on making the plugin support the latest EAP. Please see https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-intellij/issues/2279. Also feel free to add any details specific to what you are seeing on that issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Developers aware of the issue at Github's issue tracker: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-intellij/issues/2279

Thanks eshaul.